# How to show notification on tizen

Tags: c++, tizen

i need to show notification on tizen.
i've try the below code.

```
Tizen::Shell::NotificationManager notiMgr;
notiMgr.Construct();
NotificationRequest request;
request.SetAlertText(L"AlertText");
request.SetTitleText(L"TitleText");
request.SetAppMessage(L"AppMessage");
request.SetNotificationStyle(NOTIFICATION_STYLE_NORMAL);
notiMgr.Notify(request);
```

i will get notification while put this code into tizen notification example.That means this code works any form in the example.However,in my simple button click i can't.There is no error occur while click the button.But nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

As the logs say: *"The application does not have the privilege to call this method."*

If you look up [NotificationManager::Notify](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.native.apireference/classTizen_1_1Shell_1_1NotificationManager.html#aa371981444ec34588d15167eef774a2e) you'll see that it requires the privilege `http://tizen.org/privilege/notification`.

To request this priviledge for your app, open your `manifest.xml` file, click on the `Privileges` tab, click `Add...`, enter the string `http://tizen.org/privilege/notification`, click OK and rebuild/deploy your app.

Comment: Thnaks...now there is no app cras.but the functionality not working.i updated the question with current log.could you please take a look.

Comment: It works for me with the Tizen 2.2 SDK / emulator. So if you still get errors they're probably due to other parts of your code. The error message implies that you're passing either an empty string or a very long string to `Notify`.

Comment: i have change `<ApiVersion>2.2</ApiVersion>` to `<ApiVersion>2.1</ApiVersion>` then the above code works...